# Get laravel data with relation between tables

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I have the following data models:

```
class Cliente extends Model
{
     public function sector()
     {
           return $this->belongsTo(Sector::class,'sectoresId');
     }
}
class Sector extends Model
{
     public function sectorLanguage()
     {
           return $this->hasMany(SectorLanguage::class,'sectoresId');
     }

     public function cliente()
     {
          return $this->hasMany(ClienteLanguage::class,'sectoresId');
     }
}
class SectorLanguage extends Model
{
     public function sector()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sector::class,'sectoresId');
     }

     public function idioma()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo(Idioma::class,'idiomasId');
     }
}
```

I want to recover all the active clients and the name of the sector to which it belongs, if I do something like this

```
$cliente = Cliente::where('active','1');
```

When I run $client I can not enter the attribute

```
foreach($cliente as $cli) {
  $cli->sector->sectorLanguage->nombre;
}
```

Why? It only works for me when I find it by id

```
$cliente = Cliente::find(1);
echo $cliente->sector->sectorLanguage->nombre;
```

How can I get what I need without resorting to doing SQL with Query Builder.

Thank you very much, greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your defined relations, the `Sector` has many `sectorLanguage`, it means you're receiving a `collection`, so you should work on an object like this:

```
$cliente->where('active', 1)
            ->first()
            ->sector
            ->sectorLanguage
            ->first()
            ->nombre;
```

> `Cliente::where('active', 1)` and `sectorLanguage` gives you the collection, so you
>   should first get the first item from `$cliente` & `sectorLanguage` and then apply the
>   desired relationship

Hope it should work!

Comment: And how do I get  in the correct language. The clientes name is equal in all language but the sector name is diferrent.

Comment: You can use `where()` like this - `$cliente->sector->sectorLanguage->where('name', 'YOUR_NAME')->get();`.